# Per-contact notifications in Skype

Tags: windows, skype, voip

Is there any way to get Skype to show tray notifications only for specific contacts or groups of contacts, rather than for everyone or no one?

There's a shareware Skype Extra called *Contact Alarm* that claims to do this, but it runs as a separate program, creates a tray icon, and doesn't use Skype's native notifications.

Comment: Unless Skype adds the feature, it seems the Extra is the only way.  And based on the extras API documentation, it doesn't look as though a proper Skype tray notification can be created by an Extra.  FYI Extras are going away.

Comment: @Opello, move that into an answer before I do! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Skype adds the feature, it seems the Extra is the only way. And based on the extras API documentation, it doesn't look as though a proper Skype tray notification can be created by an Extra. FYI Extras are going away.

Comment: (per above, added as an answer)